# Linking static library compiled with ARMCLANG v6 with GNU gcc linker

Tags: gcc, arm, embedded, static-libraries, armclang

I have small static library compiled with latest ARM compiler ARMCLANG v6.
Now I have small application that uses this library. I am developing this application in Segger Embedded Studio to debug on Atmel SAM3x8e microcontroller.
I am trying to link this static library to my application but getting errors: undefined symbol on all functions that I am trying to use in application.
In Segger I tried GCC linker and Segger linker and the same problems.
Then I created small test library in Segger and linked with application with no problem.

Is it possible to use ARMCLANG v6 compiled library with GNU GCC linker or Segger?? May be I am missing some options that can be used to create library with ARMCLANG??

Thank you.

PS. I would use ARMCLANG for my application but license free version of ARMCLANG has code size limitations to 32K.

Comment: I'm pretty sure compilers from different vendors are different enough that you wouldn't be able to mix them. Build everything in your project with the same compiler.

Comment: What version of GCC, what version of CLANG?  If they differ greatly in age, changes to the ABI may be the issue.  For C++ the name-mangling scheme may also differ between tools.